# What is a PCS accumulator?

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, risc-v

I'm currently doing my bachelor's thesis in electronics. While reading [an article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8715007), I stumbled upon the sentence "The FPU is based on a PCS accumulator...".

What does PCS stand for? I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCS is **partial carry-save** accumulator.

From the cited paper:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

"It is based on a *Partial Carry-Save* (PCS) accumulator which aggregates
the 48 bit multiplication result".